# JQuery .toggle() submenu level 2 with glyphicon does not work

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

So what i am having is the following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right.mainmenu').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('opened');
        $(this).next('.submenu').toggle();
    });

    $('.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right.submenu').on('click', function() {
        alert("hi");
        $(this).toggleClass('opened');
        $(this).next('.submenu').toggle();
    });
});
```

My HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right mainmenu"></div>
<div class="submenu">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
     <li><a>Plapla</a></li>
     <li><a>Plapla1</a></li>
     <li><a>Plapla2</a></li>
     <li><a>Plapla3</a></li>
     <li class="submenu">
       <a>Plapla4<7a>
       <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right submenu"></div>
       <div class="submenu">
         <ul class="navbar-nav">
           <li><a>Plapla</a></li>
           <li><a>Plapla1</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

So on click on the glyphicon i am trying to open the next submenu. This is working for the first one `<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right mainmenu"></div>` but not for the second one `<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right submenu"></div>`.

I have played around a bit but can't find a solution. The code seems to be right for me.

Comment: `<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right submenu">` isn't closed anywhere and Plapla4 is incorrectly closed with `<7a>` instead of `</a>`

Comment: @LeoNapoleon Thats just a fault in my code here, i will correct it, it is closed in my local code.

Comment: Well it works for me, so the issue is I suppose that you are using css styles to hide .submenu by default - but you used this class in several occurences - containing div, the symbol to expand menu and even the list item - please change your class names to be sure you are hiding the correct divs. When I Fixed <7a> to </a> all works fine in jsfiddle. See - https://jsfiddle.net/7ejpLaf5/2/

Answer (score 0):

I changed some things in your code. I think this is what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right.mainmenu').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('opened');
    $(this).next('.submenu').toggle();
  });

  $('.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right.submenu').on('click', function() {
    alert("hi");
    $(this).toggleClass('opened');
    $(this).next('.submenu').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right mainmenu">
  Home
</div>
<div class="submenu">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li><a>Plapla</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Plapla1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Plapla2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Plapla3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="submenu">
      <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right submenu">
        <a>Plapla4</a>
      </div>
      <div class="submenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li><a>Plapla</a>
          </li>
          <li><a>Plapla1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```